# Unable to resolve symbol 'ExecutionInfo'

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm getting this error when trying to use `ReportingService2010`:

```
Unable to resolve symbol 'ExecutionInfo'
```

`ExecutionInfo` and `ExecutionHeader` worked in `ReportingService2005`. I'm using Visual Studio 2010, VB.Net, and `ReportingServices2010`.  I can connect to the server and do things like `rs.ListChildren`.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.  Hopefully this helps others.

There are two main type of endpoints in the Report Server web service, one for Management and one for execution.

The management endpoints are: ReportService2005, ReportService2006, ReportService2010
The execution endpoint is: ReportExecution2005

Therefore you can get report names, paths, data sets, etc. from ReportService2010, but to execute a report you must use ReportService2005.

So here's how you do it:

- Add a web reference to the 2005 wsdl of your server, not 2010. So do this: `http://<your server>/reportserver/ReportExecution2005.asmx` Not this: `http://<your server>/reportserver/ReportExecution2010.asmx`
- Import the referenc
- Create an instance of ReportExecutionService: `Dim rs As New ReportExecutionService.` That is the 2005 executation service that has the ExecutionInfo and ExecutionHeader methods.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155398.aspx

Comment: Your comment "Therefore you can get report names, paths, data sets, etc. from ReportService2010, but to execute a report you must use ReportService2005." really helped me.  +1